# Check if json is valid in power query

Tags: json, powerbi, powerquery

iam parsing values from json formats from a MySQL table:
the json looks like this: "{"de":"Ja","en":"Yes"}"

and my power query :

```
let
Source = MySQL.Database("ip", "db", [ReturnSingleDatabase=true]),
mapassess_maps = Source{[Schema="",Item=""]}[Data],
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(mapassess_maps, each not Text.StartsWith([title], "Is Root for Project")),
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Filtered Rows","\t"," ",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"title"}),
#"Parsed all JSON columns" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Replaced Value",{{"title", Json.Document}, {"description", Json.Document}, {"question", Json.Document}, {"answer_pos", Json.Document}, {"answer_neg", Json.Document}, {"answer_neu", Json.Document}, {"relevance_pos", Json.Document}, {"relevance_neu", Json.Document}, {"relevance_neg", Json.Document}}),

#"Expanded relevance_neg" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Parsed all JSON columns", "relevance_neg", {"de", "en", "sp", "it", "ru" }, {"relevance_neg.de", "relevance_neg.en", "relevance_neg.sp", "relevance_neg.it", "relevance_neg.ru"}) in #"Expanded relevance_neg"
```

the problem is: some values in the mysql table dont have a json format, only a hard value like: yes.

what i want is: if the value in the table is NOT in json format it must be interpreted as a value for the expanded column "relevance_neg.de".

Answer (score 0):

You can use try/otherwise. The format for it would look something like this:

`try Json.Document(value) otherwise replacementValue`

Comment: Which column are you getting the JSON from? You may need to use this inside a Table.TransformColumns call on the relevance_neg.de column.

Comment: i used here Table.TransformColumns(#"Replaced Value",{{"title", Json.Document}, {"description", Json.Document}, {"question", Json.Document}, {"answer_pos", Json.Document}, {"answer_neg", Json.Document}, {"answer_neu", Json.Document}, {"relevance_pos", Json.Document}, {"relevance_neu", Json.Document}, {"relevance_neg", Json.Document}}), but does not help

Comment: Is this value from any column or just the relevance_neg column?